# How to elegently call methods by name?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am implementing a interpreter-like functionality in a project. The goal is to allow the user of this library to call something like `Invoke(command, param1, param2, param3...)` to invoke different commands. Each command is a method of the class.

My current implementation is like:

```
class MyTest: IInvokable {
    public void Command1(string pa)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public int Command2(string pa, int a)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string Command3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public CommandResult Invoke(string cmd, params object[] p)
    {
        switch(cmd)
        {
            case "Command1":
            case "Command1Alias":
                return new CommandResult(this.Command1(p[0].ToString()));
                break;
            case "Command2":
                *** omitted ***
        }
    }
}
```

The giant `switch-case` looks really silly to me. I looked at [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) but don't know if it works here. Any suggestions to make the code better?

Comment: Use gotos. C# has them.

Comment: I'd suggest use an Attribute then use reflection to find all the methods with that attibute and then in your Invoke just look it up out of a dictionary

Comment: I believe, strategy pattern would fit for you

Comment: Put them in a dictionary<string, delegate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define two attributes to identity allowed methods to invoke, and ability to set method aliased:

```
public class CommandAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[System.AttributeUsage(validOn: System.AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CommandAliasAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CommandAliasAttribute(string alias)
    {
        Alias = alias;
    }

    public string Alias { get;}
}
```

Now we can use this to mark invokable methods:

```
public class Test
{
    [Command]
    [CommandAlias("Method1Alias")]
    public void Method1()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Method1");
    }

    [Command]
    [CommandAlias("Method2Alias")]
    public void Method2()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Method2");
    }

    public void NonInvokableMethod()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("NonInvokableMethod");
    }

}
```

Finally, let's add the invoke method:

```
public class Test
{
    [Command]
    [CommandAlias("Method1Alias")]
    public void Method1()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Method1");
    }

    [Command]
    [CommandAlias("Method2Alias")]
    public void Method2()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Method2");
    }

    public void NonInvokableMethod()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("NonInvokableMethod");
    }

    public object Invoke(string cmd)
    {
        var type = GetType();

        var methodinfo = type.GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x =>
            x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CommandAttribute)) != null //Only allow methods with the Command attribute
            &&
            (
                x.Name == cmd //Match method name
                || x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandAliasAttribute)) //Match alias
                    .Select(attr => attr as CommandAliasAttribute) //type cast to CommandAlias
                    .Any(attr => attr.Alias == cmd)
            ));

            if (methodinfo == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"No method named or aliased \"{cmd}\" was found.");

            var ret = methodinfo.Invoke(this, new object[0]);

            return ret;

    }


}
```

Test method:

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new Test();

    test.Invoke("Method1");
    test.Invoke("Method1Alias");

    try
    {
        test.Invoke("MethodX");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        test.Invoke("NonInvokableMethod");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

}
```

This example does not include usage of parameters, but i think you can figure out how to adjust the invoke method to support it. Just remember that if you wish to invoke the methods from a command prompt, for example, you will need to type-convert the parameters from string to their respective parameter types. Otherwise you will get an exception when invoking the method.

Comment: Thank you! It seems much better than my current solution! One more question: if this code is running many times in another piece of code (e.g. a script calling the functions exported here in a loop), will the performance (using reflection) be a problem?

Comment: Reflection usually have a bad reputation of poor performance, something i personally think is very exaggerated or a remnant of a poor implementation in the early days of .NET. But if you are concerned of performance you can parse and store the methodinfo members in a dictionary in the constructor and use that instead.